# Want to understand authorization,cookies,users logins,sessions

Tags: cookies, authorization, session

I want to understand the logic of authorization,cookies,users logins,sessions..Do you know any source that explain and teach me about it. If it could give any examples it would be great. I mostly use php,jsp but it would be no problem if you give answer related other languages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) is primarily used to maintain some state on the client side between the requests on a specific domain and/or path. The session is primarily used to maintain some state on the server side between the requests on a specific domain and/or path.

The session is usually backed by a cookie. In PHP it's the cookie with the name PHPSESSID and in JSP it's the cookie with the name JSESSIONID. Both contains a long, unique autogenrated value.

The server side has a mapping between the cookie value and all attached session objects in the memory. On every request, it checks the cookie value in the request header and reveals the attached session objects from the mapping using the cookie value as key. On every response it writes the cookie value to the response header. The client in turn returns it back in the header of the subsequent requests until the cookie is expired.

With regard to authorization/logins, you can put the logged-in `User` object in the server side session and check on every request if it is there and handle accordingly. On logout you just remove the `User` object from the session or invalidate the session. In PHP you can access the session by [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) and in Java/JSP by [`HttpServletRequest#getSession()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession()).

The principle is the same in all other web programming languages.

Comment: Very clearly explain @BalusC. About login/logout, it's usually advisable not to put objects (models) in the session, as this can result in hard to find errors. So in your example, instead of storing the User object, you'd store the user id, and lookup the User from that.